# Values inside savedInstanceState are nulls or default values

Tags: java, android, bundle, android-savedstate

I have a fragment and an Activity, the activity code look like this:

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("intTest", 10);
        outState.putString("stringTest", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (savedInstanceState != null){

            int test = savedInstanceState.getInt("intTest");
            String strTest = savedInstanceState.getString("stringTest");
        }
    }
}
```

and the fragment looks like this:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("intTest", 10);
        outState.putString("stringTest", "hello");

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView;
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
        int test = savedInstanceState.getInt("intTest");
                String strTest = savedInstanceState.getString("stringTest");
    }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

(The code ins simplified to understand better)

ok, In my smartphone I have android 7 and I can split the window in 2 to show 2 differents application, so when I press this button and I have my ActivityA with my FragmentA in execution, the execution of my code is as follow: `onSaveInstanceState` of `FragmentA` is called and then `onCreate` of `ActivityA` is called and enter in the section of

```
if (savedInstanceState != null){

                int test = savedInstanceState.getInt("intTest");
                String strTest = savedInstanceState.getString("stringTest");
            }
```

The problem is that the values of `savedInstanceState` are nulls o default, for example, for `strings` are `null` and for `ints` are `0`.

I think that this behavior happen when the app save its state and not only when I press the button to split the windows.

The question is why the values inside `savedInstanceState` are nulls or defaults? and how can I fix them?

Thanks

P.S `onSaveInstanceState` in ActivityA doesn't execute, only execute `onSaveInstanceState` in the FragmentA, I think this is also a strange behavior.

Edit: I think the problem is that `onSaveInstanceState` in the `FragmentA` is not called. But I don't know why it is not called.

Comment: It would help if you could verify which methods are being called. Attach the  debugger and use some breakpoints that simply log to the debug console without suspending the app.

Comment: I said it in the question, the method that are called are onSaveInstance in FragmentA and then OnCreate on ActivityA. or do you refer to the complete flow of execution?

Answer (score 0):

`onSaveInstanceState` is only called when Android system itself needs destroy the activity or fragment, e.g. phone call or low memory.

Moreover, put your values in Bundle **before** call `super.onSaveInstanceState`, after that the state was already saved.

Comment: I have seen many question, here in stackoverflow, and many examples and the `super.onSaveInstanceState` must be call before add your custom values to the save instance, however I have tried at the begining and at the end and the result is the same